# Column `x` is of unsupported type quoted call

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when

In a large dataframe ("data") with four columns I have to add another column ("Wait") with values conditionally based on the first four columns. I get the "Error: Column `Wait` is of unsupported type quoted call"

I will Prefer answers with dplyr and mutate and Case When.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
#Creating a sample dataset
#A = Datetime
#a, b and c are error codes
# 0 means successful
data <- data.frame(a = c("2018-06-01 09:00:17",
                         "2018-06-01 20:31:54",
                         "2018-06-01 20:32:49", 
                         "2018-06-01 20:34:45",
                         "2018-06-02 12:28:27",
                         "2018-06-04 22:01:58",
                         "2018-06-05 01:33:03",
                         "2018-06-05 01:33:12"),
                   b = c(0, 0, 91, 0, 522, 0,501, 501),
                   c = c(511, 250, 250, 250, 501, 511, 501, 501),
                   d = c(0, 522, 0, 559, 200, 0, 501, 501),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

#Change character to Datetime
data$a <- as_datetime(data$a, tz="GMT")
```

This is what i have written (i am not an expert in r):

```
#Error Code Vector

V <- c(91,200,250,501,511,522)

#Adding DateShift Column
data<- data %>% 
  arrange((a))%>%
  mutate(DateShift = lag(a))
data

#Calculating the WaitSecs
data <- data %>%
  mutate(Wait = case_when(b == 0 & c %in% V & d != c & d != b) ~ 1,
         (b == 0 & c %in% V & d != c & d != b) ~ 1,
         (b %in% V & c != b & d == 0) ~ 1,
         (b %in% V & c == b & d != c) ~ a - DateShift,
         TRUE ~ 0)
```

I get the error below:

"Error: Column `Wait` is of unsupported type quoted call"

Expected Result Should be:

```
data <- data.frame(a = c("2018-06-01 09:00:17",
                         "2018-06-01 20:31:54",
                         "2018-06-01 20:32:49", 
                         "2018-06-01 20:34:45",
                         "2018-06-02 12:28:27",
                         "2018-06-04 22:01:58",
                         "2018-06-05 01:31:34",
                         "2018-06-05 01:31:46",
                         "2018-06-05 01:33:03",
                         "2018-06-05 01:33:03",
                         "2018-06-05 01:33:12"),
                   b = c(0, 0, 91, 0, 522, 0, 0, 501, 0, 501, 501),
                   c = c(511, 250, 250, 250, 501, 511, 501, 501, 501, 501, 501),
                   d = c(0, 522, 0, 559, 200, 0, 501, 0, 501, 501,0),
                   DateShift = c(NA,
                     "2018-06-01 09:00:17",
                         "2018-06-01 20:31:54",
                         "2018-06-01 20:32:49", 
                         "2018-06-01 20:34:45",
                         "2018-06-02 12:28:27",
                         "2018-06-04 22:01:58",
                         "2018-06-05 01:31:34",
                         "2018-06-05 01:31:46",
                         "2018-06-05 01:33:03",
                         "2018-06-05 01:33:03"),
                   Wait = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 12, 0, 0, 9),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
data
```

I need help to resolve this. I am also open to other suggestions on how to achieve my result.

Comment: You have a misplaced parens in the first case in the `case_when` and then you'll probably want `as.numeric(a - DateShift)` to ensure that each value is of a compatible type.

Comment: Hi Joran, thanks for your response. The first line of your statement is not clear to me - "misplaced parens in the first case in the case_when". Can u explain with some code? I tried adding as.numeric(a - DateShift) and i get same error result.

Comment: You have `case_when(b == 0 & c %in% V & d != c & d != b)`, meaning you've closed the `case_when` statement before doing any assignment

Comment: Thanks. Issue resolved